# Using name group in re search and replace

Tags: python, regex

Trying to understand Python re.replace I was trying to switch groups by index or by name but encountered a problem using re to do that.

let's say:
    line = '23 24"
    #and I want to get '242 231'

```
nline = re.sub(r"(\d+) (\d+)", r"\2 \1", line)
#This will result '24 23'
```

but if I add numbers following the index - I will get invalid index:
    nline = re.sub(r"(\d+) (\d+)", r"\22 \11", line)

I have tried to use name group - but failed to make it work:
    nline = re.sub(r"(?P\d+) (?P\d+)", r"\s2 \f1", line)

```
line = '23 24"
#Trial#1
nline = re.sub(r"(\d+) (\d+)", r"\22 \11", line)
#Trial #2
nline = re.sub(r"(?P<f>\d+) (?P<s>\d+)", r"\s2 \f1", line)
```

I would like to know how to replace a group index followed by another number

and how to use group name in the back reference

Comment: I have asked regarding both index and name. The missing part was for using (?P<name>) which then can be backreferenced using /g<name>. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this alternative syntax:

```
re.sub(r"(\d+) (\d+)", r"\g<2>2 \g<1>1", "23 24")
```

> More here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub